# Get primary SMTP mail from department in Outlook addressbook

Tags: vba, outlook

I achieved resolving Names with this code from an example:

```vb
Function MailSuchen(strSuchen As String)
    Dim objEmpfaenger As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objExchBenutzer As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objExchListe As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
    
    Set objEmpfaenger = Outlook.Application.Session.CreateRecipient(strSuchen)
    objEmpfaenger.Resolve
    
    If objEmpfaenger.Resolved Then
        Select Case objEmpfaenger.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
            Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                Set objExchBenutzer = objEmpfaenger.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
                If Not (objExchBenutzer Is Nothing) Then
                    MailSuchen = objExchBenutzer.PrimarySmtpAddress
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
                Set objExchListe = objEmpfaenger.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
                If Not (objExchListe Is Nothing) Then
                    MailSuchen = objExchListe.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

This returns an e-mail address as expected if I use a Name like this:

```
MailSuchen("Max, Mustermann") => "Max.Mustermann@domain.de"
```

If I use a department Name it doesn't return anything. (Departments in my company have one corresponding mail address.)

```
MailSuchen("A 0123") => ""
```

On the other hand if I enter "A 0123" by hand in a new E-Mail as recipient and hit Alt-K it resolves to the right email address.

As I understood the resolve method should work the same as if I hit Alt-K.

Comment: If you step through your code, where does it fail?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: It does not Fail at all. It just does not resolve "A 0123" whereas the manual way with writing "A 0123" and hitting Alt-K does resolve properly. Thats why i am confused.

Comment: If i step through it the code, it skips the IF Loop, since objEmpfaenger.Resolved = False, but as mentioned above i expect it to resolve since it does when i enter it by hand in a new Mail Form.

Comment: I just learned that it might not be the shortcut alt-k but instead ctrl-k for some versions internationally. So either way what i meant was forcing auto resolve in the new Mail Form.

Comment: When you resolve the name in Outlook, does Outlook find more than one match?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: No it does resolve properly to one Mail Address. My Company has only one Mail Address per Department as Mentioned above. I cheched that and as i see it it should work :/ Im out of options here :(

Comment: I learned somethign just now that might be of interest. Some of the entries are in a different exchange forrest. Does that Matter? It shouldnt because it doesnt resolve at all, Since resolved = False when i step through it. But just for this i added another case where AddressEntryUserType = 5. Still no luck though.

Comment: Forest shouldn't matter. Is Outlook running when your code is executed? See if the name can be resolved in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - click IAddrBook button, then ResolveName. Paste "A 0123" into the Value.lpszA edit box.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: I tried several ways, but unfortunately i cant do that on my work machine since i am no admin. And i cant get to my Work Exchange Server on my private machine.

Comment: OutookSpy does not require admin permissions to install.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Its still blocked by my admins. At least thats what the windows Message says. Im sorry for causing you so much trouble. This is nagging me so hard....

Comment: You can download the dll of the appropriate bitness from http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/download/OutlookSpy.zip, copy it to any folder, and install using regsvr32.exe.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Thank you for teaching me that way!  It worked. It resolved properly. Any values you need?

Comment: So just like Outlook, it resolves the value to a single recipient, right? Does your code end up using the same Outlook profile?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Yes it does resolves to a single recipient. I do only have one outlook Profile that i know of. And for testing purposes i only use the snippet above. So yes, as far as i know it uses the same profile. Edit: I checked... only one Outlook Profile present.

Comment: Please don't put answers in question posts. You can self answer if you'd like to post an answer with different/additional information from what's already in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both Outlook and Extended MAPI work, but OOM does not, I can only suggest using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) - something along the lines:

```
Function MailSuchen(strSuchen As String)
  set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Outlook.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  Set objEmpfaenger = rSession.AddressBook.ResolveName(strSuchen)
  MailSuchen = objEmpfaenger.SMTPAddress
End Function
```

Comment: Ok, i made this work by Dimensioning the Objects since i got Option Explicit on. But now Redemption throws a MAPI_E_AMBIGUOUS_RECIP Error. I dont get why... There is only one ENtry when i search in Outlook Addressbook and it resolves fine in the New Mail Form like i mentioned above. There should only be one Entry like that... But Redemption says there is more. At least that explains that OOM does not resolve. I just dont know where the ambiguos entry comes from.. Ill try to look into Address Book Selection. Thats the only thing i can think of right now.

Comment: So i tried adding "Set AddrBuch = Session.AddressLists.Item("Globale Adressliste")" to your snippet and it still throws the ambiguous error. But my Addressbook only shows one entry for "A 0123" when i search manually...

Comment: You can try ResolveNameEx - it returns the list of matches. Try to enumerate though them. Keep in mind that if you have "A 0123" and "A 01234", they both will match.